# Configuration WildFly/HornetQ for JMS/MQ browsing

Tags: java, configuration, jms, hornetq, wildfly

I'm currently switching from Glassfish to WildFly-8.0.0.Final application server, and my MQ / JMS browser does not support the built-in HornetQ (2.4.0.Final) implementation.

After changing to JMSBrowser 2.6 (which should support HornetQ), I was unable to connect to my running WildFly instance. I presume, I need a little more configuration within the application server to make it work

Can someone supply a working wildfly `standalone.xml` or `standalone-full.xml` configuration, that has an enabled remote jmx which can be accessed by QBrowsers?

Comment: What is a QBRowser, and JMSBrowser?

Comment: It seems a question to the software provider of JMSBrowser